# Query if an azure table exists from azure logic app

Tags: json, azure

I'm trying to create a table in azure storage tables IF it does not exists already.
I did query the tablename list and put them in an array

How can query my array for an existing item , or can i can query directly azure table if a table exist ?

Here;s the array :

"value": [
      {
        "TableName": "table1"
      },
      {
        "TableName": "table2"
      },
      {
        "TableName": "table3"

Thanks!
David

Answer (score 0):

For now there is no built-in action to query if the table exists, so you have to design the flow to implement it. You could refer to my below flow.

List the tables and initialize a variable.

[image]

Do the judgement. Loop the array value and set the variable value with `contains(body('List_tables')['value'],item())`.

[image]